# Find a whole word in a string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, methods, include

I want a method that finds a word in a string, it have to be a whole array, not subarray on a string(as array.includes() does)

```
const key = ['one','two','three']
let message = 'onepiece'

    key.forEach((j) => {
    //string.prototype.includes()
    if(message.includes(j)) console.log('Method1',true); //In this way is true always there is a 'one', no matter if the string is just 'one' or 'onepiece' or 'one piece'
    else  console.log('Method1',false)
    
    //array.prototype.includes()
    if(j.includes(message)) console.log('Method2',true); //In this way is true when message = 'one'
    else  console.log('Method2',false)
});
```

The following code does what I want

```
const key = ['one','two','three']
let message = 'one'

    for (var i=0 ; message[i]!=undefined ; i++){
        mes = message.split(" ")[i]
        if(key.includes(mes)) console.log(true) //In this way is true when the message contains 'one', no matter if it's alone or in a string, but false if it's 'onepiece'
    }
```

I feel this code is highly inefficient, my question is there a simpler way to do this function?

Thx!

Comment: This was asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71758454/is-there-a-method-similar-to-includes-but-for-whole-strings

Comment: @Pellay It's not answered as I didn't explain what I want correctly

Comment: @Samathingamajig It's not the same post, I added a code that does what I want

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for intersection between two arrays since you are treating `messsage` as an array by splitting it.  In that case you could use `array.some()` to check if any words in `key` exist in `message`:

```js
const key = ['one', 'two', 'three']
let message = 'one'

let mes = message.split(' ')

let result = key.some(val => mes.includes(val))

console.log(result)

//Result is true for 'one'
//Result is true for 'one piece'
//Result is false for 'onepiece'
```